# Add 1 hour to current DateTime in PHP - Call to a member function add() on a non-object

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

I've tried multiple examples/questions around and so far I cannot get this to work. i am trying to take the current `DateTime`, add 1 hour, then set the minutes to `30`. Here is what I have:

Current Time:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s'); //this works and echos properly
```

Add hour:

```
$date->add(new DateInterval("PT1H"));
```

I receive the following error

> Call to a member function add() on a non-object

Then once that is done I'm planning to add:

```
$date->format('Y-m-d h:30:00'); //commented out on my script until I get the above piece working.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date()` does *not* produce a `DateTime()` object which is required to use `DateTime::add()`. Change:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
```

to

```
$date = new DateTime();
```

Comment: I just realized my DateTime got switched to Date - not sure when that happened.. thanks for catching that - next problem - format to YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS so I can get it in to my SQL DB.. any suggestions?

Comment: works great - thanks! I'll accept in 5 minutes when it lets me

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

```
$date = new DateTime('NOW');
$date->add(new DateInterval("PT1H"));
```

Comment: `'NOW'` is not necessary. An empty constructor defaults to "now".

Comment: Yup, you are right! It isn't wrong to add it though.